# Multiple URL login for a single Django App

Tags: django, django-urls, django-login

I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385861/multiple-login-urls-for-single-django-application). I've made another login URL for a separate set of persons. But, when I log-in, it redirects me to the primary page, rather than a secondary page for the separate set of persons.

This is because of my settings inside the setting file, which states the following:-

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  = '/dashboard/'
LOGIN_URL           = '/login/'
```

**Can I've multiple login redirect urls????**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly , here is the solution :
imagine you have group A and group B , and you want redirect group A to /LoginA/ page and group B to /LoginB/ page!
[**USE DJANGO DECORATORS**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required)
in your views.py:

```
    @login_required(redirect_field_name='my_redirect_field for A')   
    def GroupA(request):

   @login_required(redirect_field_name='my_redirect_field for B')  
    def GroupB(request):
```